# What is the distribution of n correlated Bernoulli variables?

Tags: statistics, max, correlated, discrete, bernoulli-numbers

For independent Bernoulli X_1, X_2, ..., X_n, the maximum distribution is

Y=max{X_1,X_2,⋯,X_n }~Bernoulli(1-∏_(i=1)^n▒(1-p_i ) )

But for correlated Bernoulli, what is the maximum distribution? any advice? Many thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming question and is thus off topic.

Comment: lots of people ask about mathematics and statistics on stackoverflow. I am not sure why I have to ask a computer science question?

Comment: Try this question on stats.stackexchange.com instead, where the audience is more likely to know how to answer this question.